# Django скрипт не работает на удаленном сервере

Tags: python, django, beautiful-soup, pythonanywhere

Я пользуюсь хостингом, который рекомендуют в туториале djangogirls: [pythonanywhere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com)

Скрипт - простой парсер, который отлично *работает на локальном компьютере*
(пользуюсь библиотекой `django-extensions`.

Но когда я пытаюсь запустить этот скрипт через консоль pythonanywhere, получаю ошибку:

> table = soup.find_all('table', class_='mainTableInfo')[0]
>
> IndexError: list index out of range

В чем может быть проблема?

Все библиотеки на удаленном сервере я установил.

[Сайт, который пытаюсь распарсить](http://rsr-olymp.ru)

Собственно, сам скрипт (простите за плохой код):

```
from olcalc.models import Olymp
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def run():
    url = "http://rsr-olymp.ru/"
    page_code = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page_code.content, 'html.parser')

    table = soup.find_all('table', class_='mainTableInfo')[0]
    tds = table.find_all('td')[5:]
    test_Name = []
    test_Profile = []
    test_Level = []

    except_number = True
    mode = 0
    row_value = 0

    for td in tds:
        if td.has_attr and except_number is True:
            except_number = False
        else:
            if row_value > 0:
                if mode == 0:
                    if dub_Name == test_Name[-1] and row_value != 1:
                        test_Name.append(dub_Name)
                        dub_Name = test_Name[- 1]
                    test_Profile.append(td.get_text())
                    mode += 1
                elif mode == 1:
                    mode += 1
                else:
                    test_Level.append(td.get_text())
                    row_value -= 1
                    mode = 0
                    if row_value == 0:
                        except_number = True

            else:
                test_Name.append(td.get_text())
                dub_Name = test_Name[-1]
                if td.get('rowspan'):
                    row_value = int(td.get('rowspan'))
                else:
                    row_value = 1

    for i in range (0, len(test_Name)):
        Olymp.objects.create(title=test_Name[i], subject=test_Profile[i], level=test_Level[i])
```

Текст ошибки:

```
Exception while running run() in 'olcalc.scripts.parse_olymps'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/AndreiNekrasOn/AbitInfo/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/AndreiNekrasOn/AbitInfo/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/AndreiNekrasOn/AbitInfo/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_extensions/management/email_notifications.py", line 65, in run_from_argv
    super(EmailNotificationCommand, self).run_from_argv(argv)
  File "/home/AndreiNekrasOn/AbitInfo/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 316, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/AndreiNekrasOn/AbitInfo/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_extensions/management/email_notifications.py", line 77, in execute
    super(EmailNotificationCommand, self).execute(*args, **options)
  File "/home/AndreiNekrasOn/AbitInfo/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 353, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/AndreiNekrasOn/AbitInfo/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_extensions/management/utils.py", line 59, in inner
    ret = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/AndreiNekrasOn/AbitInfo/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_extensions/management/commands/runscript.py", line 238, in handle
    run_script(mod, *script_args)
  File "/home/AndreiNekrasOn/AbitInfo/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_extensions/management/commands/runscript.py", line 148, in run_script
    mod.run(*script_args)
  File "/home/AndreiNekrasOn/AbitInfo/olcalc/scripts/parse_olymps.py", line 11, in run
    table = soup.find_all('table', class_='mainTableInfo')[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: проверьте ошибку, можете привести весь её текст, с названием файлов и строками?

Comment: Добавил сообщение об ошибке

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как посоветовали в комментариях, попробовал отловить ошибку:

```
try:
    <code>
except:
    print(soup)
```

Результат:

```
<html>
<head>
     Access Denied
  </head>
<body>
<h1>Access Denied</h1>
<p>
Access to arbitrary websites is not available from free accounts;
you can only access sites that are on our
<a href="http://www.pythonanywhere.com/whitelist">whitelist</a>.
If you want to suggest something to add to our whitelist
drop us a line at support@pythonanywhere.com.  It will have
to have an official public API.
</p>
<p>
Alternatively, you can sign up for a paid account at
<a href="http://www.pythonanywhere.com/account/">http://www.pythonanywhere.com/account/</a>
</p>
<p>
If you have already got a paid account and you're still getting this messge,
you may need to reload your web app (from the "Web" tab) or restart
your consoles.  If that doesn't help, drop us a line at support@pythonanywhere.com.
</p>
</body></html>
```

Решение - использовать другой хостинг или оплатить аккаунт на этом

Answer (score 1):

Возможно функция findall модуля soup ничего не нашла и даже индекс 0 вне диапазона. Также, в консоли pythonanywhere в папке своего проекта попробуйте сделать все миграции: manage.py makemigrations и manage.py migrate Это если проблемы с моделями

Comment: Может ли различаться работа функции findall на локальном и удаленном компьютере? Как я указал, на локальном все работает

Comment: Вряд-ли, попробуйте сделать перехват этой ошибки